# Errors installing openssh-server on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, openssh

I am not sure if the error I get is related to my apt-get setup if I do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
...
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ncurses-term openssh-client openssh-sftp-server ssh-import-id
Suggested packages:
  ssh-askpass libpam-ssh keychain monkeysphere rssh molly-guard
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ncurses-term openssh-server openssh-sftp-server ssh-import-id
The following packages will be upgraded:
  openssh-client
1 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 432 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1.222 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5.133 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'i965-va-driver:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libcrystalhd3:amd64' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: `apt-get install --fix-missing` ?

Comment: I tried the suggested solution in the post above. Now the same error comes up for another package:  `files list file for package 'libsrtp0' is missing final newline`

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue, open terminal And run following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

That's it.

Comment: THank you for the answer but it did not work. I keep getting the same error.